# how to get the first and last day of each month in a year?

Tags: sql-server

> Hello I would like to know if it is possible to get the first and last
>   date of each month in two columns, I hope you can help me thanks.

Comment: Yes, this is possible.[This post will help out](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: A 5 second Google search turned up this: http://zarez.net/?p=2462 ... please spend at least 5-10 minutes searching the web and SO before posting a question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way would be

```
DECLARE @Year int = 2004

SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(@Year, month,1),
       EOMONTH(DATEFROMPARTS(@Year, month,1))
FROM (VALUES(1), (2), (3),
            (4), (5), (6),
            (7), (8), (9),
            (10),(11),(12)
) V1(month)
```